# How to access qbfc*.dll

Tags: quickbooks, foxpro

The docs say in several places:

> The QuickBooks SDK is designed for use by a wide variety of developers in many different >development environments. Its application programming interfaces (APIs) can be used by >any programming language that is compatible with Microsoft’s Component Object Model (COM).

That surely includes FoxPro 9.  If I try to add any of the qbfc dll's as an activex library, I get an error message saying the file does not exist.

If I try to load the library directly using the com interface, this works
Declare Long DllGetClassObject in QBFC13.dll ;

But this
DllGetClassObject( ;
    lcCLSID, lcIClassFactory, @lnPtr ;
  )

gets a can't load 32 bit library error.

Should either of these work, or is there some other way to access qbfc in code?

Yes, I have a 32 bit OS and FoxPro will not compile 64 bit apps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two good articles around on talking to QuickBooks from VFP. Each uses a different approach. I've used both approaches and they both work.

QuickBooks Automation at http://tightlinecomputers.com/Downloads.htm

http://www.ita-software.com/papers/Borup_QuickBooks.pdf

Tamar

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried to fully qualify the path to the DLL?

Declare ... in "C:\SomePath\YourQuickBooks\QBFC13.dll"